# Scraping data from tables connected to each dot on a map

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium

I've written a script in python with selenium to scrape different table data lie within different dots on a map in a certain website. Each table is connected to each dot. The table is activated once either of the dots is clicked. However, my script is able to open that webpage, traverse the map, click each dot to activate each table and finally parse the data of each table available on that map. Any input on this to make it more robust  will be highly appreciated.

Here is what I've written to do the whole thing:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://acwi.gov/monitoring/vm/programs/vm_map.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))

#Using iframe link to get to the map

driver.get(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").get_attribute("src")) 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#mapDiv_zoom_slider")))

#Zooming in for the browser to locate elements properly

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#mapDiv_zoom_slider").click()

#Hardcoded time to wait until certain moment to avoid stale element error

time.sleep(5)

#Finding each tag to click to get the table

for item in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("circle"):
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(item).click().perform()

    #Go for the next item to click

    elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".titleButton.next")
    if elem.is_displayed():
        elem.click()
        time.sleep(5)

        #Finding table element

        items = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table.attrTable")))
        wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr")))
        list_of_data = [[item.text for item in data.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')]
                    for data in items.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')]
        for tab_data in list_of_data:
            print(tab_data)

driver.quit()
```

Here is a link to an image to give the clarity of my above description:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/axd66fvozexbefp/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some *key things* to take into account when using `selenium`:

- if you have an `id` of an element - use it - it's the fastest way to locate an element
- `wait.until()` returns a `WebElement` with most of the Expected Conditions - there is no need to find the element again if you want to use the element you've been waiting for
- `WebDriverWait()` can be instantiated once per driver and reused
- `time.sleep()` waits have to be avoided - they are making the code slower than needed most of the time, they are unreliable and not tied to any condition on a page, and sometimes the delay you set is not enough

#### You don't have to click through every circle on the map

We can seriously improve on web-scraping speed by extracting the "token" (let's call it this way) from the `iframe` URL and then making a REST API request to a specific endpoint with the data using `requests`:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse

import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://acwi.gov/monitoring/vm/programs/vm_map.html")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# get the token from the frame src
frame = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
token = parse_qs(urlparse(frame.get_attribute("src")).query)['webmap'][0]

driver.close()

# parse data
response = requests.get("http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/{token}/data?f=json".format(token=token))
data = response.json()

for item in data["operationalLayers"][0]["featureCollection"]["layers"][0]["featureSet"]["features"]:
    coordinates = item["geometry"]["x"], item["geometry"]["y"]
    attributes = item["attributes"]

    print(coordinates, attributes["MPN"])
```

Comment: Thanks sir alecxe, for your updated script. My head still spins to see the performance of  your code. It took no more than 3 seconds. When it comes to code for scraping the web, you are second to none. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: One little asking on this sir. Using chrome dev tools i could find that there are several json links. Is there any hard and fast rules to be sure which one to track?

Comment: @Shahin good question - I had to manually explore which of them contained the desired data. There is probably a better way to do that, but I just copied one of the titles and then looked for it in the json responses until I found the desired one. Sometimes, it's easy to see just by looking at the names of the endpoints though. Thanks, interesting question!